# Angular - race condition - multiple subscriptions at once

Tags: angular, rxjs, race-condition, subscription

I have a `UserService` which has a `getUser` method that returns an observable of type `User` class.

The `getUser` checks if the user already exists, if so, it returns the user, or else it creates a new user.

When creating a new user, it also does an API call to the 'roles' data for the user, the code looks as follows:

```js
  public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    if (!UserService.user) {
      UserService.user = new User();

      return this.getGroups().pipe(
        map(response => {
          response.value.map(v => this.setRol(v));
          return UserService.user;
        }));
    }
    else {
      return of(UserService.user);
    }
  }
```

But there is a problem.

When I subscribe to this method from two different components, one will follow the path in the first if statement, and the second will return the created user in the else statement.

But the second returns the created user before the first subscription has finished the API call to get the roles (groups) the user belongs to. which gives me errors.

How can I fix this? And what is the best practice to fix this?

Comment: `UserService.user` could be an observable and you could use [`last`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last)

Comment: What do you want in both the components? It is not a race-condition though, it is working as it should work why is that I can explain you.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara In both components I need the user and check what role the user has. The role of the user is taken by calling the getGroups method which does an http call. But I have a feeling I am doing it totally wrong like this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Caching with `shareReplay(1)`

RxJS makes a simple form of caching (like this) really easy

```ts
private userCache$ = this.getGroups().pipe(
  map(({value}) => {
    UserService.user = new User();
    value.map(v => this.setRol(v));
    return UserService.user;
  }),
  shareReplay(1)
);

public getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return userCache$;
}
```

Now `this.getGroups()` is only ever called the first time `userCache$` is subscribed to. After that, every other call waits for the API call to finish and/or gets the cached result of that call.

Answer (score 0):

I would set `UserService.user = new User();` inside of the `map` to fix this issue.

```
  public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    if (!UserService.user) {
      // remove from here
      // UserService.user = new User();

      return this.getGroups().pipe(
        map(response => {
          // add here
          UserService.user = new User();
          response.value.map(v => this.setRol(v));
          return UserService.user;
        }));
    }
    else {
      return of(UserService.user);
    }
  }
```

This way `UsesrService.user` will be set only when the API call completes.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options here,

The simplest would be to create your user inside `map` operator and improve the condition.

```
  public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return !!UserService.user?.name // name or another property that we will help us understand that the user has initialized
    ? of(UserService.user)
    : this.getGroups().pipe(
        map(response => {
          UserService.user = new User();
          response.value.map(v => this.setRol(v));
          return UserService.user;
        }));
  }
```

*PS: Usually is recommended when you have an `if-else` condition to start with the `true` part first.*

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `getUser` method, it first checks the values of `UserService.user` if it doesn't exist you call the API. However, when you inject the same service in two `components` it calls this method twice (we know that). So, when it is called second time you are assigning `UserService.user` with user instance and your `else` will always be called. The `observer` pattern is good to have and it really works well, angular also recommends it.

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {

   return new Observable(observer => {
    if (!UserService.user.checkRolesExist()) {
     UserService.user = new User();
      return this.getGroups().pipe(
        map(response => {
          response.value.map(v => this.setRol(v));
          observer.next(UserService.user);
          observer.complete();
        }));
    } else {
          observer.next(UserService.user);
          observer.complete();
     }
   });
  }
```

Now, to check whether the user exist or not, create a method on `User` class that can get you if the roles exits or not, it is just a sample to guide you:

```
public checkRolesExist() {
   return UserService.user?.length > 0
}
```